# Jest mock module that exports an enum

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a .ts file that exports an enum, which I than import from a private node module, the export looks like this

```
export enum CustomEnum {
  VAL = 'val',
  ANOTHER_VAL = 'another_val',
}
```

Than in my .vue files I can import it like:

```
import { CustomEnum } from '@custom/enums.ts'
```

And this works fine, but when I run my snapshot tests in Jest it throws the following error

```
/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@custom/enums.ts:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export enum CustomEnum {
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Any idea how I can mock this in the tests maybe entirely? Prevent jest from even loading this...?

Comment: have you tried the module.exports syntax?

Comment: I run tests against my constants, as they match with database or other settings at time, so you should not have a problem. I believe your issue is as @EduardoSousa indicated, in the syntax for the export.